# A Simple Set Theory Question

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

If B is a subset of A, then does A imply B or B imply A?

Our solution says B implies A, but since B is a subset of A, shouldn't B is included in A, and when A occurs B must occurs? Could someone tell me why does not A imply B? Or anyone agree with me.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean: If $B\subseteq A$, then do we have $(x\in A)\!\Rightarrow\!(x\in B)$ or $(x\in B)\!\Rightarrow\!(x\in A)$?

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with either probability or stochastic processes. ¶ Squares are a subset of rectangles.  Is it the case that if $x$ is a rectangle, it must be a square, or rather that if $x$ is a square, it must be a rectangle?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are sets, then "$A$ implies $B$" is not a well-formed claim. Sets are _things_; things don't imply each other. In order for something to imply something else, both somethings need to be something that can be true or false. Sets cannot be true or false; they are just sets.

Comment: A set is not a proposition, statement, sentence, formula, etc. so it cannot "imply" anything.

Answer (score 1):

Cars ($B$) are a subset of vehicles ($A$). So if you have a car ($b \in B$), you always have a vehicle ($b \in A$) -- $B$ implies $A$. If you have a vehicle ($a \in A$), $a$ may be a bike which is not a car -- it would be false to say every vehicle is a car. So $A$ does not imply $B$.

Answer (score 0):

If B is a subset of A, then, whenever you are "in B", you are "in A".  So B implies A.  But if B is a subset of A, and is not equivalent to A, then there are elements of A that are not contained in B.  Therefore, if all you know is that you are "in A", that is not enough information to conclude that you are "in B".  So A does not imply B.